# Gear ratio reading

Tags: dc-motor, robotics

I've ordered a little cheap kit of gears from Tamiya with multiple possibility os gear boxes to test.

But I'm wondering how to read the value of the ratio as I'm not sure I've understand it quite well.

So, let me know if I'm wrong on these two examples :

- 25:1 : The dc motor at source will need to operate 25 turns before the last gear accomplish a full turn
- 1:25 : The dc motor at source will need to operate 1 turn to make the last gear accomplish 25 turn ?

Is that right ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mechanics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 25:1 means 25 full rotations of the motor to achieve one full rotation of the output shaft. This is its gear **reduction** ratio.

1:25 means the output shaft will have 25 full rotations for each rotation of the motor shaft.

This is not really to do with electronic design, though.